# Netty not receiving expected amount of messages

Tags: java, netty

When I try to write a specific amount of messages to my `Netty` server only 1-3 messages are being received. I am sure that the channel is writable.

This is my testing code:

`Sending the messages`

```
Channel channel = PluginMessageClient.getClient().getChannel();

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    channel.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(new byte[]{1}));
```

`Receiving the messages`

```
public class PluginMessageServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf>
{
    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf byteBuf) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("test"); //Being printed 1-3 times (varies every time I run the message sending method).
    }
}
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: try to consume the buffer and print it, and send differnt messages. Which messages you get?

Answer (score 0):

You said that your channels are writable, but is the connection alive?
You should use the class:

```
ChannelGroup channels;
```

instead of:

```
PluginMessageClient.getClient().getChannel();
```

Because `ChannelGroup` manages automatically the life cycle of the channels.